# use excel if conditions in dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an excel binary sheet, so there are limited libraries i can refer to.
I want to implement a multiple if condition. IF A column = False ,then "Not found" should be printed in column d with header name as "Exist".
If "true" then check If column b= 2021 then "product coming soon" should be displayed else "product exist" is printed.

```
Excel equivalent:
=IF(A2=FALSE,"Not found",IF(A2=true ,IF(B=2021,"Product coming soon","Product exist")))
```

It should work for all the rows of column A.

Comment: Can you use `xlsxwriter`? https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html

Comment: No, As i want to add this column in existing sheet and Xlsxwriter does not allows it

Comment: So what are the libraries you can use?

Comment: We can use Pandas or Xlwings. I wanted to use openpyxl but i came to know that it is not compatible with binary files.

Comment: Conditionals work in pandas, so have you tried anything with them?

Comment: It seems need `np.select`